# Hierarchical query: connect_by_root does not give root value

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

I have a dataset like this one here:

| BP_ID | VALID_FROM | VALID_TO | LIMIT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15.05.1999 | 16.07.2000 | 100 |
| 1 | 01.01.2020 | 10.01.2020 | 100 |
| 1 | 10.01.2020 | 31.12.9999 | 100 |

that I wanted to "aggregate" to a single record based on the fact there is no variation in LIMIT over time for this BP_ID:

| BP_ID | VALID_FROM | VALID_TO | LIMIT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15.05.1999 | 16.07.2000 | 100 |
| 1 | 01.01.2020 | 31.12.9999 | 100 |

I thought a good idea to achieve this is to use a hierarchical query and find the root valid_from. So I tried:

```
with pretab as (

select 1 as bp_id, 
       to_date('15.05.1999', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as valid_from,
       to_date('16.07.2000', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as valid_to,
       100 as limit 
  from dual
union
    select 1 as bp_id, 
           to_date('01.01.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as valid_from,
           to_date('10.01.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as valid_to,
           100 as limit 
      from dual
union
    select 1 as bp_id, 
           to_date('10.01.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as valid_from,
          to_date('31.12.9999', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as valid_to,
           100 as limit 
      from dual

),
pretab2 as (
select t1.*, case when 
                  valid_to != coalesce(lead(valid_from) over (partition by bp_id order by valid_from), to_date('31.12.9999', 'dd.mm.yyyy'))
                  or limit !=  coalesce(lead(limit) over (partition by bp_id order by valid_from), 0)                  
              then 1 
              else 0 end as start_dummy from pretab t1
)


select bp_id, connect_by_root(valid_from), valid_to, limit from pretab2
CONNECT BY PRIOR bp_id = bp_id
and prior trunc(valid_to) = trunc(valid_from)
and prior limit = limit
start with start_dummy = 1;
```

Unfortunately, the second row does not return 01.01.2020 for the connect_by_root(). Why is that? How would I have to change the query so that it gives me this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct `CONNECT BY` version could look like

```
with pretab as (

select 1 as bp_id, 
       to_date('15.05.1999', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as valid_from,
       to_date('01.01.2000', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as valid_to,
       100 as limit 
  from dual
union
    select 1 as bp_id, 
           to_date('01.01.2000', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as valid_from,
           to_date('10.01.2000', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as valid_to,
           100 as limit 
      from dual
union
    select 1 as bp_id, 
           to_date('10.01.2000', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as valid_from,
          to_date('31.12.9999', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as valid_to,
           100 as limit 
      from dual
union
select 2 as bp_id, 
       to_date('15.05.1999', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as valid_from,
       to_date('01.01.2002', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as valid_to,
       200 as limit 
  from dual
union
    select 2 as bp_id, 
           to_date('01.01.2002', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as valid_from,
           to_date('10.01.2002', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as valid_to,
           200 as limit 
      from dual
union
    select 2 as bp_id, 
           to_date('10.01.2002', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as valid_from,
          to_date('31.12.9999', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as valid_to,
           200 as limit 
      from dual
),
pretab2 as (
select t1.*, case when 
                  valid_from != lag(valid_to, 1, valid_from - 1) over (partition by bp_id order by valid_from)
                  or limit != lag(limit, 1, limit - 1) over (partition by bp_id order by valid_from)                  
              then 1 
              else 0 end as start_dummy 
from pretab t1
)
select bp_id, valid_from, valid_to, limit
from (
   select bp_id, connect_by_root(valid_from) valid_from, valid_to, limit, row_number() over(partition by bp_id order by level desc) rn
   from pretab2
   CONNECT BY PRIOR bp_id = bp_id
      and prior trunc(valid_to) = trunc(valid_from)
      and prior limit = limit 
   start with start_dummy = 1
) where rn = 1;
```

Returns

```
BP_ID   VALID_FROM  VALID_TO    LIMIT
1   1999-05-15 00:00:00 9999-12-31 00:00:00 100
2   1999-05-15 00:00:00 9999-12-31 00:00:00 200
```

Comment: Thanks. I think because of your response I understood it finally (I hope so at least). The row that I start with is the root, which is also the ultimate parent. What I looked for was thus the leaf. Hence `select * from (
 select bp_id, connect_by_root(valid_from) valid_from, valid_to, limit, level, CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF as leaf_dummy
   from pretab2
   CONNECT BY PRIOR bp_id = bp_id
      and prior trunc(valid_to) = trunc(valid_from)
      and prior limit = limit 
   start with start_dummy = 1)` will give what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row processing:

```sql
with pretab (bp_id, valid_from, valid_to, limit) as (
  select 1, DATE '1999-05-15', DATE '2020-01-01', 100 from dual union all
  select 1, DATE '2000-01-01', DATE '2000-01-10', 100 from dual union all
  select 1, DATE '2000-01-10', DATE '9999-12-31', 100 from dual union all
  select 2, DATE '2000-01-01', DATE '2001-12-31', 100 from dual union all
  select 2, DATE '2002-01-01', DATE '2002-12-31', 100 from dual union all
  select 2, DATE '2003-01-01', DATE '2003-12-31', 200 from dual union all
  select 2, DATE '2004-01-01', DATE '2006-12-31', 100 from dual union all
  select 2, DATE '2005-01-01', DATE '2005-12-31', 100 from dual
)
SELECT *
FROM   pretab
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY bp_id
  ORDER     BY valid_from, valid_to
  MEASURES
    FIRST(limit)      AS limit,
    FIRST(valid_from) AS valid_from,
    MAX(valid_to)     AS valid_to
  PATTERN (same_overlapping_limit+)
  DEFINE
    same_overlapping_limit AS
          limit      = FIRST(limit)
      AND valid_from - INTERVAL '1' DAY <= MAX(same_overlapping_limit.valid_to)
)
```

Which, outputs:

> | BP_ID | LIMIT | VALID_FROM | VALID_TO |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 100 | 1999-05-15 00:00:00 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00 |
> | 2 | 100 | 2000-01-01 00:00:00 | 2002-12-31 00:00:00 |
> | 2 | 200 | 2003-01-01 00:00:00 | 2003-12-31 00:00:00 |
> | 2 | 100 | 2004-01-01 00:00:00 | 2006-12-31 00:00:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1b76757e2d13f0ff6e06fedc8f0c79ea)*

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `start_dummy` calculation is not returning the correct row that should be returned by the query.

If you want to use `CONNECT BY`, here is an example that will return the results you are expecting:

```sql
WITH
    pretab
    AS
        (SELECT 1                                        AS bp_id,
                TO_DATE ('15.05.1999', 'dd.mm.yyyy')     AS valid_from,
                TO_DATE ('01.01.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy')     AS valid_to,
                100                                      AS LIMIT
           FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 1                                        AS bp_id,
                TO_DATE ('01.01.2000', 'dd.mm.yyyy')     AS valid_from,
                TO_DATE ('10.01.2000', 'dd.mm.yyyy')     AS valid_to,
                100                                      AS LIMIT
           FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 1                                        AS bp_id,
                TO_DATE ('10.01.2000', 'dd.mm.yyyy')     AS valid_from,
                TO_DATE ('31.12.9999', 'dd.mm.yyyy')     AS valid_to,
                100                                      AS LIMIT
           FROM DUAL)
    SELECT bp_id,
           CONNECT_BY_ROOT (valid_from),
           valid_to,
           LIMIT
      FROM pretab
CONNECT BY     PRIOR bp_id = bp_id
           AND PRIOR TRUNC (valid_to) = TRUNC (valid_from)
           AND PRIOR LIMIT = LIMIT
  ORDER BY LEVEL DESC
     FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Another solution that will work is to use `GROUP BY`. This will only work if you are confident that you will not have any gaps in the dates.

```sql
WITH
    pretab
    AS
        (SELECT 1                                        AS bp_id,
                TO_DATE ('15.05.1999', 'dd.mm.yyyy')     AS valid_from,
                TO_DATE ('01.01.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy')     AS valid_to,
                100                                      AS LIMIT
           FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 1                                        AS bp_id,
                TO_DATE ('01.01.2000', 'dd.mm.yyyy')     AS valid_from,
                TO_DATE ('10.01.2000', 'dd.mm.yyyy')     AS valid_to,
                100                                      AS LIMIT
           FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 1                                        AS bp_id,
                TO_DATE ('10.01.2000', 'dd.mm.yyyy')     AS valid_from,
                TO_DATE ('31.12.9999', 'dd.mm.yyyy')     AS valid_to,
                100                                      AS LIMIT
           FROM DUAL)
  SELECT bp_id,
         MIN (valid_from),
         MAX (valid_to),
         LIMIT
    FROM pretab
GROUP BY bp_id, LIMIT;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I wanted to stick to the hierarchical query in order to understand it finally. So I ran your first query but this would give me connect_by_root(valid_from) 01.01.2000 where I was expecting to see 15.05.1999. So it seems like the cursor did not stop at the root but before that. Do you get the same value? Do you have an idea why this is?

Answer (score 0):

Again - if your data have no gaps and everything is consecutive as it should be, you could try "sessionization": add a session id that is incremented every time that "limit" (I renamed it to lim as it can become a reserved word) changes.
First, you add a counter that changes if the `lim` differs from the previous `lim` - using the OLAP `LAG()` function.
Second, you use the counter in an outer query to perform a running sum on it. That gives you the session id.
Finally, select from the query with the session id, and get the minimal from date and the maximal to date, grouping by `bp_id`, `lim`, and `session_id`.

```
WITH
indata(bp_id,valid_from,valid_to,lim) as (                                             
          SELECT 1,DATE '1999-05-15',DATE '2020-01-01',100 FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 1,DATE '2020-01-01',DATE '2020-01-10',100 FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 1,DATE '2020-01-10',DATE '2020-05-15',100 FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 1,DATE '2020-05-15',DATE '2021-01-01',200 FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 1,DATE '2021-01-01',DATE '2021-01-10',200 FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 1,DATE '2021-01-10',DATE '9999-12-31',200 FROM dual
)
,
with_counter AS (
  SELECT
    bp_id
  , valid_from
  , valid_to
  , lim
  , CASE WHEN lim <> LAG(lim) OVER(PARTITION BY bp_id ORDER BY valid_from)
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END AS counter
  FROM indata
)
,
with_session_id AS (
  SELECT
    bp_id
  , valid_from
  , valid_to
  , lim
  , SUM(counter) OVER(PARTITION BY bp_id ORDER BY valid_from) AS session_id
  FROM with_counter
)
SELECT
  bp_id
, MIN(valid_from) AS valid_from
, MAX(valid_to)   AS valid_to
, lim
FROM with_session_id
GROUP BY
  bp_id
, lim
, session_id;
-- out  bp_id | valid_from |  valid_to  | lim 
-- out -------+------------+------------+-----
-- out      1 | 1999-05-15 | 2020-05-15 | 100
-- out      1 | 2020-05-15 | 9999-12-31 | 200
```

Comment: Thank you. I think my MWE was not perfectly chosen because in reality the data has in fact gaps. I will adjust my question accordingly.